# Get date of creation for article in google analytics api

Tags: objective-c, swift, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How I can get date of creation for article from google analytics api?
For example, for page title I use dimensions with name `ga:pageTitle`, but can I get page creation date?

Comment: Just query for the date parameter and find the first occurrence of the page title. See the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2017-01-16&end-date=2017-05-16&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3ApageTitle%2Cga%3Adate&filters=ga%3Apagetitle%3D%3DAndroid%20Lunch%20Kit&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION&include-empty-rows=false&max-results=1000000) for an example

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've deliberately fed this information to Google Analytics (using a Custom Dimension, uploaded data, or similar), there's no way to get this.

What you can do is find the first time the page was ever visited, but that's not available through a dimension; instead you'd have to pick a series of date ranges and check for presence of the page; this would also only work if the page has consistently had traffic.